# Relation between frequency and heat

Tags: thermodynamics

Does light having more frequency like ultraviolet light mean that the heat is more?

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is somewhat wayward.

A hot body emits electromagnetic radiation over a range of wavelength/frequencies and for a body which is called a "black-body" this range of wavelengths is shown below.

[image]

You will see that a body which is at a higher **temperature** emits more ultraviolet (higher frequency and shorter wavelength) radiation than a body which is at a lower temperature.

Answer (score 0):

"You will see that a body which is at a higher temperature emits more ultraviolet (higher frequency and shorter wavelength) radiation than a body which is at a lower temperature."

This is not the case. As we see in ultraviolet catastrophe. We see that a hotter object emits lesser light at the ultraviolet end of the spectrum.

Comment: The ultraviolet catastrophe doe not exist. It was just a theoretical prediction contradicted by experiment. It has no relevance for the question here,  If you look at the curves in the answer by Farcher you can see that at 3000 K there is almost no ultraviolet whereas at 6000K a substantial part of the curve is in the UV region,